# Stackdriver Monitoring agent configuration for GCP managed deployment with docker based container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to set up Stackdriver monitoring and logging agent to be able to use them at GCP  for Managed Instance Group deployment based in instance templates with docker container and COS host.
I added special metadata `google-monitoring-enabled=true` and `google-logging-enabled=true` and doing deploy using Container Optimized Image.[image]
This is how `docker ps -a` looks at the host. You can see my own docker image and 3 stackdriver images up and running. I can even see agent metrics and processes in the Console Monitoring page.

Questions:

1. How to configure Monitoring Agent (via collectd.conf) in that case?
   I want to use JMX metrics and I have my own setup that works fine when I setup monitoring in the same instance before docker based deployment
2. How to configure Logging Agent? I have google-fluentd.conf file that works fine at the same instance with the app. But using docker deployment it didn't parse JSON logs correctly(e.g. severity)
   I did not find anything in the official documentation for that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you wanted to configure Cloud monitoring for docker based containers, where you are running JVM. I would suggest that you follow [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm#configuring) to Configuring Monitoring to monitor Java VMs. [Java Virtual Machines are monitored via JMX](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm#enabling_the_jvm_monitoring_plugin) and you need to enable the JMX plugin for monitoring.

You also might be interested in [Collecting metrics from on-premise and hybrid clou](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/blue-medora/collecting-on-prem-hybrid)d using BindPlane, a solution provided by Google Cloud's operations suite partner [Blue Medora (with GCP integration)](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/blue-medora/collecting-on-prem-hybrid), you can collect metrics from over 150 common application components, on-premise systems, and hybrid cloud systems.